# How to shift cells up after displaying pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I do have a tableView with some values from array and when I clink on the cell it should display a pickerView. This works well but when I click on the last cell and pickerView is shown, it covers the last few cells.
I would like to shift cells up once the pickerView is displayed to not cover the cells so user can see the cells (something like in Apple Health app when you click on some options).

[Apple Health App example gif to show requested state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caYOx.gif)

[Current behaviour of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGmxU.gif)

```
import UIKit

class MoreTableVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var pickerView: UIPickerView!

let mainLblArr = ["Afghanistan", "Åland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua & Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Ascension Island", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh"]
let detailLblArr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]

var pickerArr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource  = self

    pickerView = UIPickerView()

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

}

// MARk: TableView functions
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainLblArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProtoCell") as? MoreCustomCell {

        cell.mainLbl.text = mainLblArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailLbl.text = detailLblArr[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Set the position of where the picker should appear to bottom of the screen
    pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - 200, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)

    // Apply transformation to the view that will make it slide from the bottom
    pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 200)

    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    // Move the pickerView which contains picker to the subView and show it on the screen
    view.addSubview(pickerView)

    // Animates the view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.pickerView.transform = .identity
    })
}

// MARK: PickerView functions

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerArr[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerArr.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerView.removeFromSuperview()
}

}
```

Thanks in advance! Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Do not add pickerView as subview using frames. There is better solution. You can add picker view as a view of keyboard, than register for Notification when keyboard is showing and move scrollView - also it can be managed automatically by awesome library IQKeyboardManager. You will receive picker showing animation for free.

I've googled it and here is the first tutorial I found: https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/

Comment: Hi,
thanks for reply. I've seen solution as you suggested but in example above I'm not working with keyboard. Pickerview is triggered by tapping the cell. Is there any similar solution as with keyboard when you tap the cell?

Comment: To add context: the purpose of the pickerView is to select some value that will be then shown in the cell as label text. (this part is not implemented yet but just to give some background).

Comment: Then you can add invisible textfield to your cell and in delegate method return the selected data to the ViewController. In didSelectRow you can call becomeFirstReposnder method of this invisible textfield and this will create animation and picker.

Comment: Yeah that could work but it creates quite lot of clutter in the cells (especially when you laying constraints to the labels etc). I've tried that with static cells and it was working but I'm not really sure how this would work with dynamic cells (I guess there is some way). Anyway do you think this is the only way how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it’s the best. To make it even easier just add invisible text field to your view controller and then in didSelecRow call textField.becomeFirstResponder. No delegates methods and really simple. I checked and that’s what I’ve done in my app